# How do I parse an array in Swagger

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to define this json response in Swagger:

```
[{
"title": "180",
"release_year": "2011"
}, {
"title": "180",
"release_year": "2011"
}]
```

The problem is I don't know how to manage an array that is on top of the response. Every example I see would work if the Json was like this:

```
{
"films" : [{
    "title": "180",
    "release_year": "2011"
    }, {
    "title": "180",
    "release_year": "2011"
    }]
}
```

In that case I would create a component with a property "films" of type array, but what if I'm receiving the array directly?

I'm trying to define it in the response but I keep getting errors:

```
responses:
    '200':
      description: ok
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items: 
              ref: '#/components/schemas/Film'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to reference an array directly in the response:

```
    responses:
    '200':
      description: ok
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Film'
```